# Visual Studio 2015 Add Publish Version Number

Tags: c#, web, visual-studio-2015, publish

In previous VS versions adding publish version is easy. Just need to go to the project properties -> Publish and specify the publish number as shown in the below figure.

[image]

But this is the project properties window from the Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

Here I can't find any location to specify the publish version as I did on previous VS versions. So have they dropped this functionality to add publish version numbers or have they moved it to another place??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft deprecated add-ins in Visual Studio 2015 so *build number increment add-in* is no longer working.

Your possible replacement is **VsIncrementer** ([link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4050dfac-bb39-4c9e-96ed-662e3120dcf1))

Comment: Does this support publish version numbering? I need the publish version numbering functionality, not the build version numbering?

Comment: All source control tools supports tagging feature for publish version numbering. `git tag -a v1.4 -m "my version 1.4"` would be a better approach for publish versioning.

Answer (score 4):

Try This!

Its free!

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PrecisionInfinity.AutomaticVersions

**Usage:**
To configure Automatic Versions, go to the Tools Menu -> Automatic Versions Settings
Each time you build your project, the versioning will automatically change.
To use the "On Demand" version options, right click on the project and choose "Build New Version"

Hope this helps!